# I'm looking for a way to trim a string so that only 6 consecutive digits show

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The numbers are in different places within the string and have no set leading or ending characters. Using SQL Server 2008.

For example here are the shortened versions of the first three strings in the column.

```
...test on no leaks #162581 $273.85 AR

...Invoice 162481AR $160

...invoice number 162911 total $164
```

And I'm looking for the return

```
162581
162481
162911
```

I've tried using `PATINDEX` but it only is returning the amount of times there are 6 digits in the string, not the actual 6 consecutive digits.

I'm hoping to use something like this (which returns invalid length parameter) but am definitely open to other suggestions.

```
LEFT(d.Notes, CHARINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes) -1) 
AND RIGHT(d.Notes, CHARINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes) -1)
```

**Update**

Using `PATINDEX` instead of `CHARINDEX` worked to a certain extend. What about in instances where there are multiple six consecutive digits?

For example one of the strings is

```
107750 108830 Invoice 162481AR $160
```

I’m looking to return the Invoice number only (162481) or basically anything over 120000

I’ve tried using the following two formulas

```
WHEN SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6) > '120000' 
THEN SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6)
```

And

```
WHEN d.Notes LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' 
AND SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6) >= '120000'
THEN SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6)
```

But both are returning no values. Is there anything else I should be trying?

Comment: The downvotes are almost certainly because you provided no examples, what the expected results would be, and what you'd tried. Think less "I'm looking for a way" and more "This SQL isn't giving me result X, how can I change it to make it give me that result"

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!  You need to use [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) instead of [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

After that, you can use [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to pull the six numbers out.

This should work for you:

```sql
Select  SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6) 
From    YourTable d
```

If there are records in your table that do not have six consecutive numbers, you can use either of the following as well:

**To default results to `NULL` when six consecutive numbers are not found**

```
Select  Case When PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes) <> 0 
            Then SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6) 
            Else Null
        End 
From    YourTable d
```

**To not pull back results without six consecutive numbers**

```
Select  SUBSTRING(d.Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', d.Notes), 6) 
From    YourTable d
Where   d.Notes LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```